# Ref returns null when resize

Tags: reactjs, billboard.js

I've trying to get ref and want to check whether it has value.

It has value at first time, but when I resize the chart it disappears.

I think this issue would related with react not the chart library.

Any ideas?

[image: /j]
https://codesandbox.io/s/billboardjs-resize-onresize-bug-28fvz

```
const Page1 = props => {
  const [isResize, setIsResize] = useState(false);
  const chartRef = createRef();

  const options = {
    onresize(ctx) {
      console.log(chartRef.current);
      setIsResize(true);
    },
    onresized(ctx) {
      setIsResize(false);
    },
    data: {
      columns: [
        ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 170, 150, 250],
        ["data2", 130, 100, 140, 35, 110, 50]
      ],
      types: {
        data1: "line",
        data2: "area-spline"
      },
      colors: {
        data1: "red",
        data2: "green"
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Chart
        className="timelineChart"
        options={options}
        isResize={isResize}
        ref={chartRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: please validate answer if it's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is because the options object is keeping the first ref, and createRef() always return a new ref.

Use `useRef()` instead of `createRef()`

Let me know if it helps.

I tried it on JillAndMe link and it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/billboardjs-resize-onresize-bug-28fvz

Comment: well, it's easy, replace  const chartRef = createRef(); with  const chartRef = useRef();

Comment: Great! I should know the difference between createRef() and useRef()

Comment: I think it is related with functional component when I use it with craeteRef()